# Firebase - Add many apps to one project

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

This is the first time i'm working with firebase. My goal is to have a bounch of client apps (more and more over time), all of them managed by an admin app (One app to rule them all).

The thing is that the client apps have a certain content that needs to be updated from the admin app. My best approach is to create a firebase project, put the admin app there and adding client apps over time. I'have read that is possible to have an unlimited number of apps inside one Firebase project. On addition, someone told me to create one project for each client app and connect them to the same database somehow. I simply don't know what to do.

Which would be the best solution for my problem? thank you

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

A Firebase project can currently contain up to 30 app definitions. This is meant to support variations of the same logical *application*. For example, having an Admin app in addition to the app for regular users, and/or having an iOS, Android, and Web version of the same app, and for example having a free and a pro version of the app (if that is allowed by the stores where you deliver them).

Adding multiple apps to a project is expressly not meant to be used for white labeling apps, where you ship essentially the same app with different branding to different user segments, as you'd be sharing the backend services between them. For some backend services (such as database and storage) this is not necessarily a problem, as you can isolate the customers with security rules. But for other services (such as authentication and analytics) this is not possible, which is why this use-case is not supported.

If you need to define a separate app in the project for each customer, the only supported approach is to create a separate project for each customer.

> I'have read that is possible to have an unlimited number of apps inside one Firebase project.

In that case please provide a link, so we can either fix it, or (if it's not in the Firebase documentation) leave a comment to clarify.

Comment: I read it from https://firebase.google.com/support/faq , I dont need any authentication for the client apps.

Comment: I supose that I can put all the client apps in the same project, but doesnt sound like the right thing to do. If I decide to create a new project for each app, how can I make them get data from the same database? Is that even possible in Firebase? Thanks for your time

Comment: A single app *can* [connect to multiple Firebase projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects), but to secure that you'll need to sign in to the project where your database is, and that goes again against the logic I explained above. Hence my "If you need to define a separate app in the project for each customer, the only supported approach is to create a separate project for each customer."